# Какой тип шрифта выбирать в Google Fonts: Cyrillic или Cyrillic Extended?

Tags: шрифты, css

Какой тип шрифта выбирать в Google Fonts: Cyrillic или Cyrillic Extended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Кодировка Cyrillic Extended поддерживает больше языков, и следовательно вес файла больше. Использовать ее имеет смысл только если требуемый язык не поддерживается стандартной Cyrillic. Например монгольский, узбекский.

Cyrillic поддерживает русский, белорусский, украинский, сербский, болгарский и др.

Знак № входит в стандарную кодировку Cyrillic. Его наличие зависит от соответствия автором кодировки.

> Если Вам шрифт нужен только для заголовков - берите обычный. Если для >текста - extended.

Нет, для текстового нет необходимости использовать extended, если язык поддерживается стандартной кодировкой.

Answer (score 4):

Cyrillic Extended расширенный, то есть больше дополнительных символов. Шрифтов extended меньше, чем обычных.
Если Вам шрифт нужен только для заголовков - берите обычный. Если для текста - extended.

Comment: Заметил, что в regular (Ledger) может отсутствовать советский символ номер N/# (№), а в extended (Arimo) он есть, но этого не достаточно, чтобы делать выводы.

Answer (score 4):

Тоже задался этим вопросом, здесь похоже есть ответ: [Вики про кириллицу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script), 
 [Описание дополнительных символов кириллицы A](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2DE0.pdf),

 [Описание дополнительных символов кириллицы B](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA640.pdf)